# The special character cut off when cakephp save

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

Below is the database structure and in cakephp database config, I put `'encoding' => 'utf8'`, but when I save special character like "Téseau" in the ff field, it only save "T", can you anyone please tell me what is wrong here?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tt` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ff` varchar(150) NOT NULL,,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: you might save an array rather than string. Can you check that/.? can you debug your string that you are trying to save?

Comment: Thanks but I have found the solution to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The editor I use was notepad and the encoding was ansi and when I change it to utf8, it starts working.